# Images not appearing when opening HTML on Google Chrome - when inspecting getting error code "net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, error-handling

I am new to coding and currently taking a bootcamp right now learning front-end development, coding with HTML and CSS. I'm currently building my website and noticed I cannot see any of my images when running the code in google chrome. The strange part is that my tutor in my course can view the images on her computer, however I cannot see my own images when running on my browsers both Google Chrome and Safari. When going to "inspect" I notice the images are showing an error code "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" however, they the path is correct. See screenshot attached here.

I'm unsure what is going on and would appreciate any help!

[screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkg2u.png)

Comment: What do the <img src='xxxx'> tags read? (they need to be relative to the page, e.g. "../images/img1.png", or "ht tps://xxxx.com/images/img1.png,", and the directory they exist in needs to be visible to the web)

Answer (score 0):

you have to enter the proper URL paths in the src attribute of the img tags OR the image is not in the directory where it is supposed to be